# turn off to rounding numbers jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I Send a numbers form with jquery, but the descimals save without decimal.
for example 2.5 > 3 Or 17.5 > 18

```
$("#sendnomreform").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "...",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
           $('#loading').hide();
           $("#message").html(data);        
        }
   });
}));
```

input

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <input class="form-control" id="nomre<?php echo $in; ?>" required title="" name="nomre" type="number" step="any" onchange="mardodi()" onkeyup="mardodi()">
</div>
```

Comment: yes. I can send numbers or other data. but sending Of decimal numbers for example 2.5, it send 3. How to edit code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var data = new FormData(this);

data.myNumber = Number($('.myinput').val());

$.post(url, data, callback);
```

Or you can use the jQuery serialize method:

```
$.post(url, $( "form" ).serialize(), callback);
```

Comment: you can override the form with a single input value

Comment: cant send with $.ajax ?